# How to change proxy of client server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server, proxy

I want hit my api which is running on 3090 port so added proxy key in package.js like below

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3090"
    }
  }
```

but i didn't worked  why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Webpack then try setting it in Webpack.config.js file

```
  devServer: {
       historyApiFallback:true,
       proxy:{
            "/api/*":"http://localhost:3090"
        }
   }
```

Comment: What is the base path of your backend service?

Comment: i added in Webpack.config.js even though its not working

Comment: I am asking the base path. You will be setting it in index.js file like app.use(“/path”, routes) if your backend service is written in node js

Comment: const port = process.env.PORT || 3090;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

Comment: Not that. Can you share one backend Api call URL

Comment: axios.post('api/signin',data); here my expected call is localhost:3090/api/signin' but it's pointing to 3000 which is my client server

Comment: Ok. How are you making Api call from UI?

Comment: I am using axios for making http requests

Comment: I created this project using create-react-app so I didn't get web.config.js

Comment: Ok do this remove node_modules completely, delete package-lock.json and then do fresh install npm i

Comment: I didn't that no result